# How can I mix two wireless USB headsets in full duplex?

Tags: recording, audio, video, usb, wireless

I'm the editor of an ESPN affiliate website covering an NBA team. I'm shooting video and recording audio for on-court interviews during pregame when there is typically a lot of background noise. My previous setup was a sure broadcast mic to an iRig preamp to an iphone. The recording quality is actually pretty decent but I want to go to headphones so that the interviewer and subject can hear each other.

I just bought a pair of these:

http://www.turtlebeach.com/product-detail/ps3-headsets/ear-force-px3/50

And one of these:

http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/1147411-REG/jvc_gzr320bus_gz_r320_hd_memory_camcorder_black.html

I'd like to be able to record two people and allow both of them to monitor the mix so they can clearly hear each other despite the background noise. Is this even possible?

Comment: To update, Turtle Beach mislabeled my shipment and I never received my headsets. They were returned and I've now bought a pair of H2100 headsets at best buy. I also returned the JVC camera because I didn't realize it has no jack for an external mic. I've now decided to try using my smart phone as a wireless camera. I found this on combining audio from two usb devices: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MiTCNlaV56I I'm hoping to record in OBS but I haven't got it all set up yet. I'll report back with my progress.